# Time complexity with a logarithmic recursive function

Tags: python, time-complexity, mergesort

Could someone please explain the time complexity of the following bit of code:

```py
def fn(n):
    if n==0:
       linear_time_fn(n) #some function that does work in O(n) time
    else:
       linear_time_fn(n)
       fn(n//5)
```

I was under the impression that the complexity of the code is O(nlogn) while the actual complexity is be O(n). How is this function different from one like merge sort which has an O(nlogn) complexity? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(n) because `n` is smaller in each recursive level. So you have O(log n) calls to the function, but you don't do `n` units of work each time. The first call is O(n), the second call is `O(n//5)`, the next call is `O(n//5//5)`, and so on.

When you combine these, it's O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that this is O(n).  The difference between this and merge sort is that this makes one recursive call, while merge sort makes two.

So for this code, you have

- One problem of size `n`
- One problem of size `n\2`
- One problem of size `n\4`
- ...

With merge sort, you have

- One problem of size `n`
- which yields two problems of size `n/2`
- which yields four problems of size `n/4`
- ...
- which yields n problems of size 1.

In the first case, you have n + n/2 + n/4 + ... = 1.

In the second case you have 1 + 1 + 1 + .... 1, but after log2(n) steps, you reach the end.